# Change PyADS Cycle Time (variable update time)

Tags: python, twincat, twincat-ads

I have a signal that is **continuously updated** (at about 200 Hz). I am using **PyADS** (write_by_name) to write to a global variable in my Beckhoff IPC. I concurrently run a scope project and export results. **My PLC Cycle time is 1 ms** so all of the variables of interest are collected at 1 ms intervals by the Scope Project. But the global **variable that is written via PyADS is collected at 100 ms** intervals. Ideally, I'd like the variable written by PyADS to be updated at ~10 ms (or the PLC Cycle Time of 1 ms). Since this global variable is part of the same task which is run at 1 ms, I assume this difference (1 ms vs 100 ms) is being created by PyADS. Is that correct? Is there a way to change the refresh time/cycle time in PyADS? Or is there some issue at play here?

The Python code uses a while loop to continuously push new data to the variable in IPC:

```
while(True):
        plc.write_by_name('GVL_LIST.variable', value, pyads.PLCTYPE_REAL)
```

Have reviewed PyADS documentation but could not find any mention of cycle time.

Answer (score 1):

ADS is not meant for fast, real time, communication. I don't think there is a way that you can speed it up by software settings. It is just a property of the protocol.

I did find [this link which talks about fast-ADS](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/bk9000/2802211467.html?id=7975344480390796083). I mentions cycle times < 1 ms, but it requires special hardware.

Comment: Would buffering the data and writing to an array (idealy with timestamps for extra precision) be some sort of workaround? Seems like something that might do the trick, though I am not completely sure what the aim of the project is in the first place. Just my suggestion. Never used PyAds though.